# passing select option and a php variable vai ajax to php page where query is build to retrive the data from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a main page where user selects an employee id , which redirects him to next page and that employee id is stored in $n1 here . There in new page there is a select option , which selects month with values 1-12 for each month .i want to create an AJAX call which takes the employee id "$n1" and then -- > select name="s1" onchange="getdata(this.value)"...then the select value and the employee id should be sent vai ajax to php script to build a query like "select * from table1 where empid="$n1" and month="$q""

Comment: need to show enough html/javascript to compile data from that needs sending. SHow what you have tried so far

Comment: Thanx mahn ... i figured it out .